# Why binary mode when reading/writing TOML in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8, toml

When reading a `toml` file in normal read (`"r"`) mode, I get an error

```py
import tomli

with open("path_to_file/conf.toml", "r") as f: # have to use "rb" !
    toml_dict = tomli.load(f)
```

> TypeError: File must be opened in binary mode, e.g. use `open('foo.toml', 'rb')`

Same happens when writing a `toml` file. Why?

[tomli github readme](https://github.com/hukkin/tomli) says

> The file must be opened in binary mode (with the "rb" flag). Binary mode will enforce decoding the file as UTF-8 with universal newlines disabled, both of which are required to correctly parse TOML.

I thought the age of typewriters was over, so why is the "universal newline" not allowed? [toml spec](https://toml.io/en/v1.0.0#spec) says "*Newline means LF (0x0A) or CRLF (0x0D 0x0A)*" (poor Mac users) - that also doesn't clarify the reason to me... so, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm just guessing: in text mode Python does *some* interpretation of the data. The TOML specification is probably *pretty specific* about how to interpret bytes and turn them into meaningful data. If *any* of the interpretation from Python isn't exactly what TOML requires, then it's best to implement parsing TOML files based on the raw (uninterpreted) binary data. I suspect that this is what's happening here. For example: text files already include interpreting the encoidng. If TOML files **must** be UTF-8 then only the binary mode can detect errors in this case.

Comment: So **my misconception** seems to have been that using `open` in "r" / text mode would allow to enforce a specific decoding such as UTF-8. That is not the case. Pretty obvious in hindsight... I was distracted by "universal newlines disabled". Learned something today. Besides, tomli enforces UTF-8 decoding by [calling](https://github.com/hukkin/tomli/blob/1bd3345f97cba795d7e6075956815c0a52151ed0/src/tomli/_parser.py#L61) [bytes.decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) on the byte stream returned  by `open`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To wrap this up, the problem/behavior described in the question is actually a specific case of a more **general problem**: how to enforce a specific decoding when reading a text file with Python's [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) built-in. Or rephrased: **ensure the file has a specific encoding**.

`tomli` requires the user to handle the file IO, so the user could also use an arbitrary encoding in `open(path-to-file, "r", encoding=...)`. However, the `toml` specification requires the input to be UTF-8. `tomli` implements this requirement by forcing the user to use binary mode `"b"` when reading the file, then does the decoding based on the read bytes ([src](https://github.com/hukkin/tomli/blob/1bd3345f97cba795d7e6075956815c0a52151ed0/src/tomli/_parser.py#L61)).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> As mentioned in the Overview, Python distinguishes between binary and text I/O. Files opened in binary mode (including 'b' in the mode argument) return contents as bytes objects without any decoding. In text mode (the default, or when 't' is included in the mode argument), the contents of the file are returned as str, the bytes having been first decoded using a platform-dependent encoding or using the specified encoding if given.

Apparently, tomli (I don't know that module) expects to be fed a byte object, not text.

Comment: Yeah, I admit I left out the important point and @JoachimSauer wrote it down nicely. He should get the accepted answer. A lot of modules in python expect raw bytes to decode for themselves.

Comment: What I wasn't aware of is that you cannot ensure a specific decoding (UTF-8 in this case) when consuming the output of `open` in "r" / text-mode. Seems pretty obvious in hindsight... you can still update your answer if you like.

Comment: I won't update. @JoachimSauer wrote it down perfectly in his comment. While I _meant_ the same, I didn't _write_ the same.

Comment: FYI, the now built-in TOML reader [`tomllib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tomllib.html) in Python 3.11 also requires `'rb'`.